# 2 setInterval at different intervals modifying the same array

Tags: node.js, socket.io, data-integrity

If i create a first setInterval that push every 1 milisecond an item in my array, and then i have another setInterval (every one second) that copy this array and reset it (the original one).

Will i be sure that i don't erase data  ? since the first interval write every 1 milisecond, and the second interval reset the array every one second ?

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t1d20usr/

```
var data = [];

var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {

  data.push(i);
  i++;

  if(i== 10000) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

}, 1);

setInterval(function() {

  var recentData = data;
  //i want to be sure that this will not erase something set between the set of recentData and the reset of this array 
  data = [];   

  $('.container').append(recentData.join(',')');

}, 1000);
```

It works great, but due to the logic, i wonder if sometimes i could lost data.

Why am i doing this ? Because i get a lot of requests from different clients (socket emits) and i want to broadcast their request to others client only once every second instead of broadcasting on each emit from each client that is overkill. This is similar to how multiplayer game servers works. (My jsfiddle and the intervals is an example to simulate requests, i don't do it like that ! Eventually i will get emits at different intervals and will broadcast them every 30ms or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is robust. Why? Javascript is single threaded. Each interval function runs to completion before the next one starts.

You might consider thinking about this as a queue. Your 1ms interval function puts elements onto the queue, and your 1s function takes all the queued elements off the queue in one go.

Your technique of replacing the `data` array with an empty one works well. You won't get any duplicates that way.

If you wanted to consume one item from your `data` array, you could use

```
   const item = data.length > 0 ? data.shift() : null
```

but that does a lot of shuffling of the elements of the array. Use your favorite search engine to find higher-performance queue implementations.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do. But to be able to take elements from the queue i need to remove them, aka reset the array (so i don't take them again on next interval). Unless there is another solution ?

Comment: This is what i came with unshift and pop : http://jsfiddle.net/t1d20usr/1/ what do you think @o-jones ? Or another version (maybe more performant ? ) with push and shift : http://jsfiddle.net/t1d20usr/2/

Comment: Here's what I use.  https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/1c0b05caf5527b33c3bafba67f92e529 `.shift()` and `.unshift()` are too slow for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

The code is safe. As O. Jones said, the single threaded nature of javascript will ensure that you will not loose any element in the array.

But I'd like to add a consideration: don't expect that, when the 1s interval is reached, the length of data is 1000 (1s = 1000ms). The length of the data array will always be different and often much lower than 1000.
Expecially under stress (1ms interval is a bit stressing), javascript can't handle the load taking a time lower than 1ms.

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tfk9yhL2/) modified version of your fiddle.
On my machine, this is logging a length in a range of 248 / 253 elements pushed every 1s.

```
var data = [];

var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {

  data.push(i);
  i++;

  if(i== 10000) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

}, 1);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(data.length)
  var recentData = data;
  data = [];

  $('.container').append(recentData.join(',') + '<span class="iteration">/</span>');

}, 1000);
```

Comment: wel since i'm in nodejs and using sockets, it will be events based. So the first interval doesn't really exist, it will only be socket event adding data tot he array. And the 1000 ms interval taking the data array, broadcasting it and resetting it. But i guess it's still ok ?